# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in pcntl_fork()

Tags: php, linux, process, centos

I have some agents running, and after several weeks of normal mode, suddenly we get:

`Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded`

on a line that is

`$this->pids[$next_child] = pcntl_fork();`

also we have:

```
[root@a ~]# ulimit -u
385913

[root@a ~]# ps ax | wc -l
400

[root@a ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
4194303

strace shows

poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLHUP}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
```

we are on php5.4 centos, could it be a PHP bug? or what could be wrong?
**update** 
2 years after still having this error, since then we upgraded to php5.6 then to php7, and now to php7.3.1

Comment: check your top processes, something hung?

Comment: no, there are no hangs, load is on 0.1

Comment: That definitely doesn't look like a PHP bug. `pcntl_fork()` directly uses the fork(2) system call. I don't know the fork() syscall implementation, but it looks like poll() is called to wait for successful process creation in a loop. That's just speculating now... you'd have to look at the Linux source to exactly get what's going on here so that strace could help you more…

Comment: @bwoebi We didn't had this issue on php5.3, once we upgraded to php5.4 we keep having this once per week.

Comment: @Pentium10 Well, then there's something else bogus, but not the pnctl_fork() call. It's implementation didn't change since PHP 4. So: what you described here is not sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: @bwoebi I can provide more details, just don't know what.

Comment: @Pentium10 can u reproduce the problem in a sample project? maybe with a pnctl_fork() loop ...

Comment: @Pentium10 well, we can't tell that you either. Maybe it just fails here because fork() is a slow operation and 299.97 seconds already passed at that moment, but the cause is somewhere else. The only thing which is clear, is that pnctl_fork() isn't the origin of the problem.

Comment: @Pentium10 It's hard to find out your problem without more information.

Comment: The `ulimit` commands you show are not useful from the shell -- put them in a PHP script and run them under your web server to find out what they really are.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: @ParhamDoustdar NO I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a bit cryptic. So, we must do some debugging to get to the bottom of the issue.

**Note:** Rather than concentrating on the function `pcntl_fork` or PHP bugs. I'll concentrate on this being a system resource issue. Because, the line it throwing the error contains fork. We'll see where it goes from there

- The error might be a bug or unimportant. To test this add `ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);` to the very top of your script. If your script runs as intended without any problems, then it is true. If not, then we should examine the behavior. If your agents start having problems serving clients around the time they would normal throw the error, that might mean the error meant something along the lines of resources not being enough. If that's not the case you should examine the behavior of the agents so you can learn more about the cause of the issue.
- The error might be related to the size of Active URL cache being too high if you are using it from what I've heard.

If the problem still persists, you need to provide more information about your environment and configurations so that we can help you.

**Question:** Are you by any chance using Magento?

Comment: It's a custom PHP agent system, it's not Magento.

Comment: @Pentium10 I saw a thread having the same problem using `Magento` so I thought it might be related. But, I guess my answer didn't help at all since you downvoted.

Comment: It's not my downvote, anyway you just repeat what other told. As more weeks passed, and keeps having every 7-10 days and not in masses, random at different agents, but the same machine, and only this having PHP5.4 I still consider it's a PHP bug.

Comment: @Pentium10 Are you logging the activity of the agents? Resource usage, Events, etc. in addition to the errors? `PHP 5.4` might have a subtle change affecting your setup rather than having a bug. It might ultimately be a bug. But, it's better safe than sorry.

Comment: I do have logs, and collectd and even StatsD data and Graphite stats. Nothing shows an exhaust of services. Also I checked how other services are working, and there is no faults on others. If it from a system limit, that would let fail other services on the same machine redis, galera, elasticsearch. But none of them are affected.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say exactly without knowing the whole body of the code... but my first inclination would be to ensure that you're properly killing the processes once the script is done. Without that, peek usage might exhaust resources to handle the new process, but due to their nature the 'die' very differently.

Ensure that you're not assuming that you're killing the process with exit, try
`posix_kill( $this->pids[ $next_child ], 15 );`

You can try using sig 9 instead of 15, but I wouldn't suggest using it in production - however it may help debug the problem. Actually, you might check for a 9, that might be the problem...  `posix_kill( $this->pids[ $next_child ], 9 );` won't do any cleanup.